# when i am putting the while loop inside a function why is the answer coming different?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, web-deployment

```js
var count = 99;
var word = "bottles";

 
    
   
   {
   
 
  
     while(count>0){
      if(count === 1){
       var word = "bottle";
                           }
         console.log( count + word +" beer on the wall, " + count + word + "  of beer. take one down and pass it around, " );
     count--;
       if(count>0){
      if(count === 1){
        var word = "bottle";
                           }
     console.log( count + word + " beer on the wall.");
                        }
 else{
  if(count<1){
   var word = "bottles";
                   }
  console.log("no more " + word + " of beer on the wall.");
     }
    }
  }
```

and when i am putting it inside a function the result changes.

```js
var count = 99;
var word = "bottles";

 
    
   
  function myName() {
   
 
  
     while(count>0){
      if(count === 1){
       var word = "bottle";
                           }
         console.log( count + word +" beer on the wall, " + count + word + "  of beer. take one down and pass it around, " );
     count--;
       if(count>0){
      if(count === 1){
        var word = "bottle";
                           }
     console.log( count + word + " beer on the wall.");
                        }
 else{
  if(count<1){
   var word = "bottles";
                   }
  console.log("no more " + word + " of beer on the wall.");
     }
    }
  }
  myName();
```

can anybody please tell me what is going wrong with putting function against the while loop. you can run the code in the snippet and see the difference of results. also the code looks a lot untidy can anyone suggest me ways to reduce the lines.

Comment: tidy your code in the snippets to make it readable

Comment: The reason is that by using the keyword `var` you are re-declaring the variable inside the function, and it's a different variable than the one with the same name outside the function. You shouldn't use `var` when assigning a value to the variable, only when declaring it.

Comment: @Bravo can you please help me this one so that i can take it as a reference to make my subsequent codes as tidy as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue come from the declaration of another word variable inside if

```
if(count === 1){
    var word = "bottle";
}
```

when you do this you declare a word variable only available in the if bracket

an idea to enhance your code is to have the two word bottle and bottles inside variables and calculate a true word at begining of while iteration

```
    var finalWord = (count === 1) ? word : words;
```

```js
var count = 99;
var words = "bottles";
var word = "bottle";

function myName() {

  while (count > 0) {
    var finalWord = (count === 1) ? word : words;
    console.log(count + finalWord + " beer on the wall, " + count + finalWord + "  of beer. take one down and pass it around, ");
    count--;
    if (count > 0) {
      console.log(count + finalWord + " beer on the wall.");
    } else {
      console.log("no more " + finalWord + " of beer on the wall.");
    }
  }
}
myName();
```

Comment: can you please explain how did you defined the variable finalword ??

Comment: finalWord is affect by a ternary boolean the syntax is `(condition) ? value1: value2` you can avoid used variable with this syntax :  `var finalWord = (count === 1) ? 'bottle' : 'bottles';`